# Flutter CameraImage image streams to the Imageview

Tags: flutter, image, http, video-streaming

I am getting an issue while converting the cameraImage to normal image and view it in Imageview.

here is the code

```
void _startStreaming() async {
    try {
      if (!_controller!.value.isStreamingImages) {
        setState(() {
          _isStreaming = true;
        });
        _controller?.startImageStream((CameraImage image) {
        if (_isStreaming) {
        _convertCameraImageToBytes(image);
      }
   });
  }
 } catch (e) {}
}
```

Some of the images are processed well and some of them are not.
I want send these streams to backend,
I will be so thankfull if someone can help me with it.